# How to share two ISP in two router configuration?

Tags: networking

I have two router configured in lab. To configure network redundancy, I want to configure one ISP on each router.
So if network on one router goes down, we will have the network connectivity from other router.

[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: Do you only want/care about outbound internet access, or inbound as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make something like "heartbeat" between R1 and R2, to share "gateway ip address" set up on your PC.

Do you have own IP range? If yes, you need on both router BGP protocol to propagate it to internet.
If not, and it is simplier, you have to NAT your connection on router, but when your router go down, your connection fail and you need establish new one (reload web page on computer ...)

Comment: HI Martin, I want on the failure of ISP connected to router1 other IPS automatically starts work, without any configuration change on router 2.

Comment: You will need at least VRRP protocol for share "gateway ip address" beetwen router. It's implemented in "keepalived" package. Example is well writen on http://louwrentius.com/configuring-attacking-and-securing-vrrp-on-linux.html

Comment: And of course you have to write own script to test ISP connection on router. At least ping to two or three destination in internet through ISP. If all fall, you have to shutdown "shared" ip address on router with problem.